# File Logo.png does not exist in Android Studio when i try to create image asset

Tags: android, android-studio, android-image, android-assets, uiimageasset

[image: Screensort]

When I try to create action icon in Image Asset of Android Studio I saw the error log: ***logo.png does not exist*** and I can not create **Action bar and Tab bar icon**. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hey, if you found a solution please share it with me

Comment: look for "ic_launcher.png" in .../app/src/main/res/minimap/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Find the file  .idea/assetWizardSettings.xml (by pressing ctrl + shift + n inside the project and typing in assetWizardSettings.xml) and find inside it the not found file name by the system (ex. logo.png), then delete that row or simply delete .idea and reimport project

Comment: please explain in detail.

Comment: @Arbaz.in what kind of details you need?

Comment: can you explain location of that file? actually i can't found that file

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+n and start typing file name on opened dialog

Comment: its working after deleting that row from **assetWizardSettings.xml** file

Comment: Where do we find this file ? Couldn't find it anywhere unfortunately:/